# python - using json with OrderedDict and Datetime

Tags: python, json

I am using python to encode an OrderedDict with timestamp in it and I am having issues. The data that I am trying to encode looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('a', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 15, 15, 58, 54, 884000)), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')])
```

I expect this to be json encoded and decoded to get exactly the same data.

In order to encode timestamp directly, without changing to ISO or Unix time, I used bson's json_util interface as below. It works correctly.

```
json.dumps(str, default=json_util.default)
json.loads(jsonstr, object_hook=json_util.object_hook)
```

In order to get an OrderedDict I used object_pairs_hook, which also works:

```
json.loads(x, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

However, when used together, the two things mess with each other and the result is not in the correct format(Since the bson interface is creating an extra dictionary for the timestamp).

```
json.loads(jsonstr, object_hook=json_util.object_hook, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

This query ends up getting this:

```
OrderedDict([(u'a', OrderedDict([(u'$date', 1434383934884L)])), (u'b', u'b'), (u'c', u'c'), (u'd', u'd')])
```

The timestamp is not parsed out correctly. Any suggestions on how to do that correctly? (Pickle may be a direction but I am seeking other solutions first).

Comment: What does ``json_util.object_hook`` output for ``datetime`` objects?

Comment: @JamesMills it output '{"a": {"$date": 1434383934884}, "b": "b", "c": "c", "d": "d"}'.  This extra dictionary is parsed as OrderDict by object_pairs_hook thus stopping object_hook to decode it.

Comment: So it's encoded as a UNIX Timestamp as ``{"$date": "<timestamp>"}``?

Comment: @JamesMills Yes, exactly. I can do the same myself, yet it's a huge json and I don't want to traverse the structure first to modify the timestamp and traverse it again when decoding to change timestamp back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own decoder which will handle both datetime and OrderedDict and use it in `object_pairs_hook`. For convenience and testing I also defined my own encoder but you are free to use the one you have already.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

# Test dictionary
a = OrderedDict([('a', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 15, 15, 58, 54, 884000)),
                 ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')])
print(a)

# Encoder for datetime
def encoder(obj):
    if type(obj) is datetime.datetime:
        return {'$date$': obj.timestamp()}
    raise TypeError

# Encode
s = json.dumps(a, default=encoder)
print("JSON:", s)

# Decoder for OrderedDict and datetime
def decoder(obj):
    if len(obj) == 1 and len(obj[0]) == 2 and obj[0][0] == '$date$':
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(obj[0][1])
    else:
        return OrderedDict(obj)

# Decode
b = json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=decoder)
print(b)

# Compare
print("Comparing:", a == b)
```

This will print:

```
OrderedDict([('a', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 15, 15, 58, 54, 884000)), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')])
JSON: {"a": {"$date$": 1434409134.884}, "b": "b", "c": "c", "d": "d"}
OrderedDict([('a', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 15, 15, 58, 54, 884000)), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')])
Comparing: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you encode/decode the datetime object directly?

```
import datetime as dt
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

datetime_encoding = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M.%S %f'

od = OrderedDict([('a', dt.datetime(2015, 6, 15, 15, 58, 54, 884000).strftime(datetime_encoding)), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')])

x = json.dumps(od)

od_new = json.loads(x)
od_new['a'] = dt.datetime.strptime(od_new['a'], datetime_encoding)

>>> od_new
{u'a': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 15, 15, 58, 54, 884000),
 u'b': u'b',
 u'c': u'c',
 u'd': u'd'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In reality it's a very large python dictionary with nested dictionary and nested timestamp. I am trying to avoid manually traversing through the data and change the datetime myself. And then traverse again when decoding to change that back.

Comment: Yes, we all hope life is as easy as the example above. :)